# How do I find my network prefix?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am reading Python Networking book:

When a network device generates network traffic
that needs to be sent across a network, it first compares the destination's IP address with its own network prefix.

My nmcli:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         70:4D:7B:41:40:67
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.12/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::94ea:6996:dd8b:8eec/64
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

Where is network prefix?

Comment: I think this is it `192.168.0.12/24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your address is:

```
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.12/24
```

`/24` means that first 24 bits are network address and the remaining 8 bits (which can be used to create a range between 0-255) are for host addressing.

So in `x.x.x.y` the network prefix is `x.x.x` (192.168.0.0) and the `y` (12) is host address.

Host addressing would start with 1 up to 254 and 255 would be the broadcasting address.